# undefined on logging array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

```
var obj1 = []

obj1 = positionx.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
   return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
}, {});
```

positionx is an array of a bunch of repeated objects like

```
[
  'Orchestrator', 'Architect',      'Liaison',        'Analyst',
  'Liaison',      'Officer',        'Liaison',        'Liaison',
  'Coordinator',  'Specialist',     'Orchestrator',   'Designer',
  'Planner',      'Orchestrator',   'Developer',      'Supervisor',
  'Executive'....
]
```

`console.log(obj1)` gives

```
{
  Orchestrator: 5,
  Architect: 6,
  Liaison: 7,
  Analyst: 7,
  Officer: 2,
  Coordinator: 3,
  Specialist: 6,
  Designer: 2,
  ...
}
```

But `console.log(obj1[1])` outputs `undefined`

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `obj1[1]` as you show, there is, for example, `obj1["Orchestrator"]`. The keys are all words, not numbers

Comment: You're not logging an array you're logging an object.

Comment: right! i tried logging  ```console.log(obj1["Orchestrator"])``` which returned undefined too.

Comment: @HarshithLax [That works](https://jsbin.com/sugipifeqe/edit?js,console). If it doesn't for you, then there is no indication in your question as to what might be wrong. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Right, I JSON.stringify-ied it before commenting, in a hurry. Apologies
and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your output is an object which contains keys. Objects do not really have an implicit order and must be referenced by their keys.

```
obj1[1] // doesn't make sense because obj1 is an object, not an array.
obj1["Architect"] // does make sense and would equal 6.
```

If you want to iterate through an object similar to how you would iterate through an array, you would want to do something like this:

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => console.log(key, obj1[key]));
```

Notice in this case, that the array that we are iterating on is the array of keys in that object. There is no implicit order so we can't reliably expect the n-th value of an object to always be the same. If you were to for example just get the first key in an object, there is no guarantee that the name of that key will be "Orchestrator".

Answer (score -2):

You are passing an empty object as initialValue to your reduce function; this means  after the reduce is finished obj1 becomes an object; check here [the definion for reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).